# .draggable change message when i click "Ctrl"

Tags: jquery, user-interface

I would like to show(and change) the message to 'copy' or 'move' while I'm clicking <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>

javascript:

```
$('.draggable').draggable({ 
    revert: 'invalid',
    cursor: 'move',

    helper: function(event) {
        return $( '<div>'+$(this).text()+'<div class="ui-widget-header"></div>' );
    },              
    start: function(event) {
        if(event.ctrlKey) {
            $('.ui-widget-header').text('copy');
        } else {
            $('.ui-widget-header').text('move');
        }
    },      
    drag: function(event) {
        if(event.ctrlKey) {
            $('.ui-widget-header').text('copy');
        } else {
            $('.ui-widget-header').text('move');
        }
    },
    stop: function(event) {
        if(event.ctrlKey) {
            $('.ui-widget-header').text('copy');
        } else {
            $('.ui-widget-header').text('move');
        }
    }       
});
```

This script is working while I'm draging.
But, it's not, if I start or stop draging.

1. mouse click on the .draggable, then click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>. ---> it's not working.
2. mouse drag, then click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>. ---> it's working.
3. mouse drag and stop it, then click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>. ---> it's not working.

This for droppable

```
$('.show_twitterlist').droppable({

    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",       
    drop: function(event, ui) {         

        if(event.ctrlKey) {
            intype = 'copy';
            ui.helper.html('<div>'+ui.draggable.text()+'<div class="ui-widget-header">copy</div>');
        } else {
            intype = 'moveto';
            ui.helper.html('<div>'+ui.draggable.text()+'<div class="ui-widget-header">move</div>');
        }

        ...
    }
});
```

Can anyone give me some ideas?
Thank you for helping.